# How to change default text color of application?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I set text color of all Fields to white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such option in BB API. You can only override `Field.paint(Grahpics grahpics)`, smth like this:

```
...
public void paint(Grahpics grahpics) {
    int initialColor = grahpics.getColor(); // just in case
    grahpics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    super.paint(grahpics);
    grahpics.setColor(initialColor);
}
...
```

So you could create a set of custom white-colored Fields (WhiteLabelField, WhiteEditField, etc.) and use them istead of the originals.

Comment: I have already custom classes for all fields. So it is not a problem for me to copy the code to these classes. It works, thank you very much. You are really so helpful again!